# When I use speech to text for the second time for language translation in Flutter, it gives an error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, translation, speech-to-text

I am trying to develop an application for language translation in flutter. This application converts speech to text and displays it on the screen with speech to text. The text translated from speech to text is updated instantly on the screen. Every time the text is updated, I try to translate the spoken sentences into a different language with the translator package. When I click the button and speak for the first time, instant translation is made. It works correctly, but when I click the button for the second time, I get an error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpXOq.png)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:avatar_glow/avatar_glow.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;
import 'package:translate_app/colors.dart';
import 'package:highlight_text/highlight_text.dart';
import 'package:translator_plus/translator_plus.dart';

class SpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpeechScreenState createState() => _SpeechScreenState();
}

class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
  final translator = GoogleTranslator();
  final Map<String, HighlightedWord> _highlights = {
    'flutter': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('flutter'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  };

  late stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _text = 'Çevrilecek Metin';
  String _translatedText = 'çevrilmiş metin';
  final targetLanguage = 'tr';
  Timer? _timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        title: const Text('Speech to Text Demo'),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: AvatarGlow(
        animate: _isListening,
        glowColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        endRadius: 75.0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        repeatPauseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        repeat: true,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => {
            _listen(),
            if (_timer != null) {_timer?.cancel()}
          },
          child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextHighlight(
                  text: _text,
                  words: _highlights,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextHighlight(
                  text: _translatedText,
                  words: _highlights,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _listen() async {
    if (!_isListening) {
      bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
      );
      if (available) {
        setState(() => _isListening = true);
        _speech.listen(
          onResult: (val) async {


            setState(() {
              _text = val.recognizedWords;
   
              _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
                translate(translator, _text, targetLanguage);
              });
            });
          },
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      _speech.stop();

    
      if (_timer != null) {
        _timer?.cancel();
      }
    }
  }

  void translate(
      GoogleTranslator translator, String text, String targetLanguage) async {
    final translation = await translator.translate(text, to: targetLanguage);
    setState(() {
      _translatedText = translation.text;
    });
    print("Translated: $translation");
  }
}
```

```
I tried resetting the timer, creating a new timer every time, constantly sending requests without a timer, and creating a single timer in the method and using it, but I got the same error in all of them.
```